# "Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set WindowActionBar to false in your theme to use a toolbar instead"

Tags: java, android

I get the error "Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set WindowActionBar to false in your theme to use a toolbar instead" whenever I try to run my app in the emulator on Android Studio and it crashes upon startup. I understand that this question has been asked before, but when I remove the `extends AppCompatActivity` as I am told to do in other posts it then gives me an error for the `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` line a bit further down in the code.

As far as I understand this is an error with Android Studio getting confused about the native toolbar and the toolbar that I'm trying to implement. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the crux of the problem? Why is it giving me an error for `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` once I get rid of the extends statement?

The main activity is using the "AppTheme"

Thanks.

MainActivity Code for reference:

```
package com.treehouse.android.movies;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

//extends AppCompatActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    static public ArrayList<Movie> moviesList;
    static public ArrayList<String> images;
    public String mostPopular="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=";
    public String highRated="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=";
    //Make both GridAdapter and GridView non-Static?
    static public GridAdapter gridAdapter;
    static public GridView gridView;
    public static boolean connectionEnabled;
    public Context currentContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        String result="";
        moviesList=new ArrayList<>();
        images=new ArrayList<>();
        currentContext=getApplicationContext();


        if (isNetworkAvailable()!= false) {
            connectionEnabled=true;
            getJsonData(0);
            new GetMovies(currentContext);
            gridView =(GridView) findViewById(R.id.moviesGridView);
            gridAdapter =new GridAdapter(MainActivity.this,moviesList,images);
            gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent movieIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailsActivity.class);
                    Log.i("Default position ", String.valueOf(position));
                    movieIntent.putExtra("position",position);
                    startActivity(movieIntent);
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network Is Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            connectionEnabled=false;
        }



    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }


    //get json file
    //0 for most popular
    //1 for highest-rated
    public void getJsonData(int searchBy){
        GetMovies downloadTask=new GetMovies(currentContext);
        try {
            if (searchBy == 0 ){
                downloadTask.execute(mostPopular);
            }
            else if(searchBy == 1){
                downloadTask.execute(highRated);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.mostpopular_button) {
            if (isNetworkAvailable()!= false) {
                new GetMovies(currentContext).execute(mostPopular);
                gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Network Is Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else if (id== R.id.highrated_button){
            if (isNetworkAvailable()!= false) {
                new GetMovies(currentContext).execute(highRated);
                gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Network Is Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Styles Code for reference:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Manifest Code for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.treehouse.android.movies" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >
        <!-- android:theme="@style/AppTheme" part of application -->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                    />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rest of MainActivity.java. It would also be helpful to see your styles.xml file (and, ideally, to know which style you're using for your activity).

Comment: I've added the rest of the Java code as well as the xml style code. Upon revisiting the error it's telling me: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Comment: In your manifest, is your activity's theme `AppTheme.NoActionBar`?

Comment: It appears to be set to AppTheme. You can probably tell, but the themes portion of android confuses me a bit. Should I just simplify it and get rid of most of the Themes in the Style code and go for one uniform style?

Answer (score 7):

change your style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

replace to this :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since your Activity's theme is set to `AppTheme`, it comes with an "action bar" by default. When you then call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`, your app crashes because you've already got an actionbar (from your theme).

Simply change your Activity's theme to `AppTheme.NoActionBar` in your manifest.

Comment: Unfortunately, after implementing that change the error still occurred. I've also tried changing the ```extends AppCompatActivity``` to just ```Activity``` and that didn't work either.